# Loading external website in popup window using Colorbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

In the examples offered by the official site
http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example2/

This website http://threadless.com opens in a popup window successfully.

I successfully implemented this example, but I couldn't load any other page.

For example

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="colorbox.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%"});
        });
    </script>
<body>
    <p><a class='iframe' href="http://threadless.com">Outside Webpage (Iframe)</a></p>
</body>
```

This code works perfectly, but when I replace threadless.com with google.com, facebook.com, or any other website a blank popup appears. Could anyone help me please?

Thanks very much.

Comment: you cant put google in iframe

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700636/how-to-show-google-com-in-an-iframe

check the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could possibly create a simple page with a google search box and whatever else you need, then open that in the iFrame instead of google.com...

Do you want the results of the search to show in the iFrame or a new window though?

Comment: I was just trying to learn how to use Colorbox. Thanks very much.