# Remote Host of iframe

Tags: php, javascript, dns

I have iframes over various websites. In my js, I'm hitting against a php file in a different domain. Is there a way to get the domain name for the server on which my iframes are hosted. (This is to prevent others hitting against my php file).

Example.
I have a domain called `www.domain.com` and another call `www.phpscript.com`
If my website is embeded in `yahoo`. Is there any way that I can find out that my js calls are coming from `www.domain.com` and not some dodgy website?

`$_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']` and `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` would not work in this situation, as `REMOTE_ADDR` would provide the users IP and `REMOTE_HOST` would return `yahoo`.

Comment: There's only the http referer, which is not always available, and most definitely never reliable.

Comment: That's a problem, it wouldn't be reliable enough :( and wouldn't it return `yahoo` as well?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to allow interaction across frames but only within a subset of domains, then you'd need to the [Content Security Protection](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/content-security-policy/raw-file/tip/csp-specification.dev.html) extensions. Currently this is only implemented in Firefox and Chrome (not MISE, don't know about Safari and Opera etc) but it's a w3c standard so expect everyone to join in eventually.

Hence for a php script runing on Example.com allowing access from other.com (or vice versa)....

```
$ok="'self',*.other.com,*.example.com";
$policy="default-src $ok; frame-ancestors: $ok";
header("X-Content-Security-Policy: $policy");
header("X-Webkit-CSP: $policy");
header("Content-Security-Policy: $policy");
```

NB there are other implications when you enable CSP.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

The OP wanted to do the reverse of what I initially interpreted the question as.

**To prevent a site being accessed when it *IS NOT* in an iframe,** you can use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.top === window.self) {

    window.self.location = 'about:blank'; 
    window.self.onload=function(evt){ 
        window.self.location = 'about:blank'; 
        document.body.innerHTML=''; 
    };
    document.body.innerHTML='';
}
</script>
```

This requires JavaScript to be enabled, and will blank the page and redirect to about:blank (nothing) if the page is accessed outside of an iframe.

---

**To preventing a page from being accessed when it *IS* in an iframe** (original answer, still useful).

You can send the header `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` [(what Google does)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700636/how-to-show-google-com-in-an-iframe?answertab=active#tab-top) to ask the browser to not display the content in a frame that's not on your domain.

**PHP**

```
header('X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block');
header('X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN');
```

You could additionally work around this with JavaScript to stop access to the site through iframes:

```
if (window.top !== window.self) { 
    window.self.location = 'about:blank'; 
    window.self.onload=function(evt){ 
        window.self.location = 'about:blank'; 
        document.body.innerHTML=''; 
    }; 
    document.body.innerHTML='';
}
```

Both of these methods rely on the browser support, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: The site is built around being used in iframes. As it's a video player. So blocking the iframe isn't a solution.

Comment: If you only had that JavaScript on the top frame, that would work - other frames don't have to have that script included (granted then a savvy user could embed the non protected frame). Are your frames loading full pages or just content.

Comment: Has all the required html tags and the video player + it's components.

Comment: You should be able to put that JavaScript on just the parent page then. At any rate, the headers you can set in PHP should be effective enough and won't prevent you accessing your own frames.

Comment: The video players are on more than 100+ sites. They're also on different domains in which I don't have access too

Comment: @Bankzilla Can you try to give a clearer example in your question? It seems to be a cross between preventing XSS attacks on your site and stopping people embedding your site in an iframe on other sites. 

_"The video players are on more than 100+ sites"_ - the code in my answer is to stop others embedding your site, neither will prevent you embedding other sites in yours. Again, please clear your question up.

Comment: Has nothing to do with stopping users embeding the site as an iframe. I'm trying to stop outside sources hitting against `www.phpscript.com` so only `www.domain.com` is allowed to access the script inside of it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12889/discussion-between-stecman-and-bankzilla)