# Why does google.com not load in an iFrame

Tags: html, iframe, web

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to show google.com in an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700636/how-to-show-google-com-in-an-iframe)

I am researching possible methods of running a proxy server for a school project.

I thought about using iframes to load a web page inside another web page, so I made a test.

Here is my HTML:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <IFRAME SRC="http://google.com" WIDTH=1024 HEIGHT=768>
      Not loaded
    </IFRAME>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, http://google.com doesn't load, and instead the iframe remains white.

On further inspection, Google Chrome's GET request to load google.com has been cancelled.

I suspect that google stop people from loading their site in iframes, but why is this, and what are the effects of it?

---

**Edit:**
I forgot to mention, other websites (like my [own](http://todddavies.co.uk)) work fine.

Comment: The effects are pretty obvious: a few lines extra in their JS and nobody can load google.com in an iframe.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to show google.com in an iframe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700636/how-to-show-google-com-in-an-iframe) > The reason for this is, that Google is sending an "X-Frame-Options:
> SAMEORIGIN" response header. This option prevents the browser from
> displaying iFrames that are not hosted on the same domain as the
> parent page. See: [Mozilla Developer Network - The X-Frame-Options
> response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header)

Comment: @ArthurHalma http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78658/is-it-okay-to-copy-paste-answers-from-other-questions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because it has X-Frame-Options Header policy and browsers tend to respect those policies.

[Read here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header) and [here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-websec-x-frame-options-00#page-3)

> The "X-Frame-Options" allows a secure web page from host B to declare
> that its content (for example a button, links, text, etc.) must not
> be displayed in a frame of another page (e.g. from host A).  In
> principle this is done by a policy declared in the HTTP header and
> obeyed by conform browser implementations.

Comment: X-Frame-Options .. same thing ..