# Are iframes supposed to work with plunkr?

Tags: html, iframe, plunker

I'm trying to make a plunkr that uses an iframe to embed content. [Here is what I have so far.](http://plnkr.co/edit/XTNENqjBxwciNn6qUso4) Am I doing it wrong? It just shows an empty iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iFrames work in plunker. It just depends on the the source.

For example try the following:

```
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/CoO64eNigDnddXfjM6uv?p=preview)**

Google prevents the browser from displaying the Google site in iFrames that are not on web page on the Google domain.

[How to show google.com in an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700636/how-to-show-google-com-in-an-iframe)