# Firefox doesn't hide dive when using jquery hide()

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, dialog, show-hide

So I've trying to get Firefox to hide a div on page load without much success. It works in Chrome and IE though.
My HTML looks like this

```
<div id="container">
  <iframe src="www.google.com"></iframe>
</div>

<a href="#" id="showBtn">Show</a>
```

And my Javascript looks like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#container").dialog({ autoOpen: false, Title: "Hello, World!" });
  $("#container").hide(0);

  $("#showBtn").bind("click", function () {
    $("#container").dialog("open");
  });
});
```

So here's what I'm trying to do. On page load, the #container would be hidden and remain so until user clicks the 'Show' button.

Comment: did u tried with hide(); without parameters ?

Comment: @EnterJQ yeah, I did.

Comment: replace .bind with .on

Comment: Oh actually, hide() WITHOUT parameter magically works! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="container">
    <iframe src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>
</div>

<a href="#" id="showBtn">Show</a>
```

jquery code

```
$('#showBtn').click(function () 
{

  $("#container").css("display","");

});

window.load=$("#container").css("display","none");
```

Answer (score 0):

That works fine in Firefox 19.0 on Mac OS X (as it does in Chrome). Your issue might be with the content you are trying to put in an iframe. It won't work with Google.

[Functioning jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c8n34/) (code is same, included as StackOverflow requires it):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#container").dialog({ autoOpen: false, Title: "Hello, World!" });
  $("#container").hide(0);

  $("#showBtn").bind("click", function () {
    $("#container").dialog("open");
  });
});
```

The reason why Google won't work in an iframe: [How to show google.com in an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700636/how-to-show-google-com-in-an-iframe).

You may find that some versions of jQuery with certain browsers won't work if `hide` has an invalid parameter of `0`.

Answer (score 0):

As @EnterJQ pointed out, hide() without parameter solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

You can not load google into iframe. see:  [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header)

Answer (score 0):

do it in this way

```
<div id="container" class="display-none">
  <iframe src="www.google.com"></iframe>
</div>

<a href="#" id="showBtn">Show</a>
```

css

```
.display-none{
display:none;
}
```

initially your div would be hidden and when the user clicks show button just toggle the class.

```
$("#container").toggleClass('display-none');
```

hope this helps.