# Why Colobox iframe does not open the page?

Tags: iframe, colorbox

I've used colorbox in my project to show some details in a jQuery popup window. But the target page does not appear.
This is the code :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/colorbox.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"70%", height:"70%"});
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<a href="http://www.google.com" class="iframe" style="color:#333">Click here</a>
</body>
</html>
```

You can see at [Here](http://www.drugdis.com/test.php).
What's the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to display google.com in an iframe which is not as easy as with other sides.
It should work the way you did it with almost any other side.

Read this for more information: [How to show google.com in an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700636/how-to-show-google-com-in-an-iframe)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure with your purpose but if you want to embed google search on your website with iframe, you can try http://www.google.com/custom.
You can see demo here http://jsfiddle.net/devchill/LVunZ/

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/custom" class="iframe" style="color:#333">Click here</a>

$(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"70%", height:"70%"});
```