# Echoing an iframe based on logic in php

Tags: php, iframe, echo

I am in a nasty situation. I am trying to `echo` an iframe in php based on an if statement. However this returns a blank space.

I think this is due to the wrong escaping [single/double quotation] but can't figure it out :(

My code:

```
echo '<iframe src="'.$the_iframe_calling_url.'" frameborder="0"></iframe>';
```

any luck on this?

Okay, here is my code with if block. I am stuck with this :(

```
//check if this is image or not
    if (($file_type === 'image/gif')or($file_type === 'image/jpeg')or($file_type === 'image/jpg')or($file_type === 'image/pjpeg')or($file_type === 'image/x-png')or($file_type === 'image/png') ){
        echo '<img src="'.$final_file_url.'" width="70%" />';
        }

    else{

    $the_iframe_calling_url = 'https://docs.google.com/viewer?url='.$final_file_url; //http url

    //echo $final_file_url;
    echo '<iframe src="'.$the_iframe_calling_url.'" frameborder="0"></iframe>';


    echo $the_iframe_calling_url;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're going to have to add more code. At the very least, you need to give us the `if` statement and the definition of `$the_iframe_calling_url`. What does the outputted HTML look like?

Comment: $the_iframe_calling_url is perfectly okay. the value of $the_iframe_calling_url is https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://acssales.net/data/uploads/tweaks.docx and it is a valid link

Comment: OK. So what is your code outputting? Can you add the rendered HTML to your question? Is the echo even being called?

Comment: @andrewsi: My code is outputting a blank iframe box :( but this should contain the targeted data from URL.

Comment: Look at the source of the page you're generating. What is the `src` attribute for your `<iframe>`? Is it correct, or not?

Comment: @andrewsi: the src is perfect. I echoed it and it is completely okay.

Comment: If you change the src to a random website, it works; but with this specific URL, you're not getting anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code. Maybe the url your are trying to open is the problem. `$the_iframe_calling_url`

Or the if statement that was said in the comment

Since you posted the URL you are trying to show in an Iframe here is your answer:

[Iframe google problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700636/how-to-show-google-com-in-an-iframe)

Comment: this is the reason!! I get it. Thank you so very much Jorge :)