# iframe not able to load website properly

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, pentaho

I am using following code for making an frame and displaying it on my website. Login page of website is displaying properly but when i am logging in, Home page is unable to load properly.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function makeFrame() {
    ifrm = document.createElement("IFRAME");
    ifrm.setAttribute("src", "http://54.200.2.210:8080/pentaho/Login");
    ifrm.style.width = 800 + "px";
    ifrm.style.height = 1200 + "px";
    document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
}
```

Below is the code for calling this function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    makeFrame();
</script>
```

Comment: More information would be helpful here, the full page with any console messages as a minimum really. Difficult to diagnose what is (or isn't!) happening from just that snippet.

Comment: There's nothing wrong or unusual with your code here, so the problem is likely with the other site or the rest of your page. You can try checking your JavaScript console for any error messages, or post more of the code that makes up the various pages.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to embed content from another domain in your iframe it will not load because of the same-origin-policy. You can bypass that by accessing a script on your domain instead of the original url, which will then load the content from that url (e.g. via file_get_contents in php) and echo it.

Read the answer to this question: [does not permit cross-origin framing iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19921676/does-not-permit-cross-origin-framing-iframe)

JS

```
ifrm.src = "http://yourdomain.com/yourscript.php?url="+encodeURI("http://54.200.2.210:8080/pentaho/Login");
```

PHP

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents($_GET['url']);
?>
```

OF COURSE you will have to make it more secure then just this one line of PHP!

Comment: This isn't quite right. You can point an `<iframe>` `src` to any domain, and the content will load just fine. The restriction only comes in to play if the frame wishes to interact with its parent via JavaScript, or vice-versa.