# Google maps issue: does not permit cross-origin framing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, iframe

I am having a problem with the embedded custom google maps with `iframe`.
It gives the error as below.

> does not permit cross-origin framing.

And I want to change the content of the `iframe` to a "map cannot be displayed" picture. Or is there a built in trigger for the api, to send an error, not a blank `iframe`?

My event handling looks like this:

```
if ($("#mapframe>iframe").contents().find('body').html().length == 0) {
   $(this).contents().find('body').html('<h1>Üres</h1>');
}
```

Comment: You cannot access DOM of iframes which are not in the exaclty same domain of your page for security measures, this is why you get `cross-origin` error., you should change your approach

Comment: The original problem you're trying to get around appears to be related to your logged-in state on the browser. https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps-engine/4emg5D1Gwuo/discussion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some restriction with [origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). It is not possible to use a short link in this case.

The error tell you that URL that you pass is not suitable as a source for `iframe`. Here is example URL:

```
Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://maps.google.com/?ie=UTF8&ll=48.858151,2.293611&spn=0.00648,0.021973&t=h&z=16 does not permit cross-origin framing.
```

[Does not permit cross-origin framing iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27918380/2798643) follow it also.

Comment: I think the original problem is at Google's end. If they want you to embed maps, which they give you the tools to do, then they need to turn of the x-xss-protection header.