# One link for a page with multiple URLs

Tags: url, button, hyperlink, flash-cs6

I have a page that has three separate URLs on it. There is a top menu, a side menu, and the main content url. I did not create this page, I just need to link to it for a Flash CS6 button.

Is there a way to create ONE url that opens a webpage with all three of the above url's?

Answer (score 1):

You need to somehow create an intermediate page which contains [frames](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/frames.html), [iframes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/frames.html#h-16.5), or similar, for each of the subdocuments. It could look more or less like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <iframe src="http://www.python.org"></iframe>
    <iframe src="http://www.codinghorror.com"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then link to this document.

If you absolutely can't store an intermediate document anywhere, and you're okay with tight space constraints on the intermediate page, you may be able to use a [data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme). This is a link that contains the data of the linked-to document in the URI itself. It looks like this:

```
<a href="data:text/html;base64,PGh0bWw+PGJvZHk+PGlmcmFtZSBzcmM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cucHl0aG9uLm9yZyI+PC9pZnJhbWU+PGlmcmFtZSBzcmM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cuY29kaW5naG9ycm9yLmNvbSI+PC9pZnJhbWU+PC9ib2R5PjwvaHRtbD4=">
Link
</a>
```

The [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)-encoded data in this URI is equivalent to the document above. When the user follows the link, their browser will decode the Base64 data, parse the result as HTML and show the page as usual.

Note that I had to choose example sites carefully above, because a lot of the "usual suspects" have [the header "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN" set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700636/how-to-show-google-com-in-an-iframe), preventing you from including them as a frame from a different domain. If this is the case for any of the sites you're trying to include as subdocuments, you may have to try a different approach.