# How to set an iframe src attribute set in CRM 2013 using javascript?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2013

I have defined a web resource as follows:

```
function setIframe_OnLoad() {
    var iFrame = Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get('IFRAME_docmgmt');
    var url = iFrame.getSrc();
    if (url.indexOf("blank") != -1) {
        setiFrameUrl();
    }
}

function setiFrameUrl() {
    debugger;
    var url = 'http://www.google.com';
    Xrm.Page.getControl('IFRAME_docmgmt').setSrc(url);
}
```

And I have configured the url of an iframe named `docmgmt` to `about:blank`. I wired up the `OnReadyStateComplete` event of the iframe to the `setIframe_OnLoad` function. When I load my CRM 2013 form, the debugger line is hit and I can step through and see that the `Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get('IFRAME_docmgmt').getSrc()` value does indeed change to `http://www.google.com`. When the function completes, the page reloads. I don't know why. When it reloads, the iframe is set to `about:blank` again. Does anyone have a working code sample for setting an iFrame URL programmatically using javascript in Dynamics CRM 2013?

Comment: Is this all URLs?  Have you tried https to avoid mixed mode?

Comment: Good point. It's actually not mixed, both are http

Answer (score 1):

www.google.com wont work because next error:

Refused to display 'https://www.google.com.bo/?gws_rd=cr&ei=XZKQU6_YA6HNsQTkhIKIBA' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to **'SAMEORIGIN'.** More references [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700636/how-to-show-google-com-in-an-iframe).

So as the start page is set to about:blank this remains after **.setSrc** function.
Actually there are many sites which does not allow use theirs webpages as iFrames.

I wrote same code that you but using **http://www.bing.com** and it is working pretty fine :)