# 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'. error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cross-domain

I am getting this error.

```
Refused to display 'https://www.google.com.au/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=uPilVOfREaGN8QfsvIGABQ&gws_rd=ssl' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
```

I have made an html5 ad and upload on my Ad server which generates a script and i place that script on the page to test the ad. The page loads ad in an iframe.

I have a very simple link to open the google.com page in my orignal index page but i am getting this error in the test page.

```
  <div id="container">
        <div id="ad" class="collapsed">
        </div>
        <div id="left_panel" >  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/owais.ahmed.96" id="example">Testing!</a>
        </div>
        <div id="right_panel"  ></div>
    </div>
```

[image: Error]

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to open google on another domain however the header on the google page is set to same origin, e.g same domain.

Please also see this related question:

[How to show google.com in an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700636/how-to-show-google-com-in-an-iframe)