# Cross Domain issue : HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<iframe src ="http://google.com" width="400" height="300">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

How can i get this result done?

I know CORS and jsonp are solution for this . But i really dont know how to implement it . I dont have any javascript on my pages . Just normal html pages. If its not possible doing just html codes then how can i achieve my goal using

> javascript

or

> jquery

.I want to get google.com in my iFrame .

Comment: You forgot to write the actual problem description...

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Did you do ***any*** research at all? I just Googled your request and I found so much information about HTML5 and Javascript CORS. If you don't know how to implement it, learn Javascript, and learn Google.

Comment: I did but couldnt get any actual solution @PaparazzoKid

Comment: @PeeHaa and nicael i want to see real google page in my iframe

Answer (score 0):

Google is preventing you from embedding their website into your iFrame, since you're not on the same domain (*.google.com).

Also: [there are a ton of questions like this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700636/how-to-show-google-com-in-an-iframe) Check [this answer in particular](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25854093/1647315) -- it's not what you want, but it might be good enough.