# Javascript - reload sites in infinite loop

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have problem with reloading a list of sites in infinite loop.
When in first time I tried do it without iframe, the first site was loaded and nothing else happend. I want to reload some sites from list into iframe. There should be no buttons to reload site, it should be automatic -> show site, wait 20 sec, show site2, wait 60 sec... I want to have different delays, so thats way there is a sleep in infinite loop.
In this point I stucked :) 
Below is my (rubbish :) ) example I tried to run.
Any ideas how to do it easy and small as possible ?

```js
<html>
  
<head>
  
  <script language="JavaScript" type = "text/javascript">
    
    function sleep(delay) {
     var start = new Date().getTime();
     while (new Date().getTime() < start + delay);
    }
  
    function changeSites() {
      while(true){
        document.getElementById('myFrame').setAttribute('src', "http://www.google.com/");
        sleep(4000);
        document.getElementById('myFrame').setAttribute('src', "http://www.yahoo.com/");
        sleep(2000);
        document.getElementById('myFrame').setAttribute('src', "http://stackoverflow.com/");
        sleep(5000);
     }
    }

  </script>
  
</head>

<body>
    
  <iframe id="myFrame" width=100% height=100% >
    
   <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
   
  </iframe>

  <script language="JavaScript" type = "text/javascript">
    
    changeSites();

  </script>
  
 </body>
  
</html>
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: You don't use `thread.sleep` in JS as it is single threaded, you will lock up the browser. Use `window.setTimeout` /  `window.setInterval` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Well what you could do is the following:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

var urls = ["http://www.google.com/", "http://www.yahoo.com/", "https://stackoverflow.com/"];
var index = 0;
setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById('myFrame').setAttribute('src', urls[index]);
    index = index+1;
    if(index > urls.length-1) {
        index = 0;
    }
}, 20000);
</script>
```

Except Google and others won't allow this. See  [How to show google.com in an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700636/how-to-show-google-com-in-an-iframe). You should probably have control over embedded sites in iframe or use CORS etc. for sites you want to embed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this:

```
var sites = [
    { 'src' : 'http://www.google.com', 'delay' : 4000 },
    { 'src' : 'http://www.github.com', 'delay' : 6000 }
];
var index = 0, time, lastUpdate = new Date().getTime();

function showNextSite () {
    document.getElementById('myFrame').setAttribute('src', sites[index].src);
    lastUpdate = new Date().getTime();
    index++;
    if(index >= sites.length)
        index = 0;
}

setInterval(function () {
    time = new Date().getTime();
    if (time >= lastUpdate + sites[index].delay)
        showNextSite();
}, 1000); // lets only check this every second
```