# Python with Folium: How can I embed a webpage in the popup?

Tags: javascript, python, html, leaflet, folium

I'm working on a simple implementation of [Python Folium](http://folium.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) with simple markers based on [this page](http://bl.ocks.org/wrobstory/5609718).

```
import folium
map_1 = folium.Map(location=[45.372, -121.6972], zoom_start=12,
                   tiles='Stamen Terrain')
map_1.simple_marker([45.3288, -121.6625], popup='Mt. Hood Meadows')
map_1.simple_marker([45.3311, -121.7113], popup='Timberline Lodge')
map_1.create_map(path='mthood.html')
```

I can include HTML in the popup, but I'd like to embed a webpage. Here is my mock-up.

[image]

Is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here a quick example of how I proceed :

```
def get_frame(url,width,height):
html = """ 
        <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <iframe id="myIFrame" width="{}" height="{}" src={}""".format(width,height,url) + """ frameborder="0"></iframe>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var resizeIFrame = function(event) {
        var loc = document.location;
        if (event.origin != loc.protocol + '//' + loc.host) return;

        var myIFrame = document.getElementById('myIFrame');
        if (myIFrame) {
            myIFrame.style.height = event.data.h + "px";
            myIFrame.style.width  = event.data.w + "px";
        }
    };
    if (window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener("message", resizeIFrame, false);
    } else if (window.attachEvent) {
        window.attachEvent("onmessage", resizeIFrame);
    }
    </script>
    </html>"""

popup = get_frame(url,
                  width,
                  height)

marker = folium.CircleMarker([lat,lon],
                             radius=radius,
                             color='#3186cc',
                             fill_color = '#3186cc',
                             popup=popup)

marker.add_to(map)



iframe = folium.element.IFrame(html=html,width=width,height=height)
popup = folium.Popup(iframe,max_width=width)
return popup
```

I took the script from [this link](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/css/display-iframe-contents-without-scrollbars.html#fbid=3zoeT7_mQll), and you can check running the code snippet

```html
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <head>
            
        
            <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        
            
        
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
        
        
        
            
        
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        
        
        
            
        
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        
        
        
            
        
            <script src="https://rawgithub.com/lvoogdt/Leaflet.awesome-markers/2.0/develop/dist/leaflet.awesome-markers.js"></script>
        
        
        
            
        
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.markercluster/0.4.0/leaflet.markercluster-src.js"></script>
        
        
        
            
        
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.markercluster/0.4.0/leaflet.markercluster.js"></script>
        
        
        
            
        
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.3/leaflet.css" />
        
        
        
            
        
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        
        
        
            
        
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
        
        
        
            
        
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
        
        
        
            
        
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/lvoogdt/Leaflet.awesome-markers/2.0/develop/dist/leaflet.awesome-markers.css" />
        
        
        
            
        
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.markercluster/0.4.0/MarkerCluster.Default.css" />
        
        
        
            
        
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.markercluster/0.4.0/MarkerCluster.css" />
        
        
        
            
        
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-visualization/folium/master/folium/templates/leaflet.awesome.rotate.css" />
        
        
        
            
            <style>

            html, body {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                }

            #map {
                position:absolute;
                top:0;
                bottom:0;
                right:0;
                left:0;
                }
            </style>
            
        
            
            <style> #map_b2063da716d14361b72b0f9a50315884 {
                position : relative;
                width : 100.0%;
                height: 100.0%;
                left: 0.0%;
                top: 0.0%;
                }
            </style>
        
        
        
        </head>
        <body>
            
        
            
            <div class="folium-map" id="map_b2063da716d14361b72b0f9a50315884" ></div>
        
        
        
        </body>
        <script>
            
        
            

            var southWest = L.latLng(-90, -180);
            var northEast = L.latLng(90, 180);
            var bounds = L.latLngBounds(southWest, northEast);

            var map_b2063da716d14361b72b0f9a50315884 = L.map('map_b2063da716d14361b72b0f9a50315884', {
                                           center:[37.38583,-5.99306],
                                           zoom: 12,
                                           maxBounds: bounds,
                                           layers: [],
                                           crs: L.CRS.EPSG3857
                                         });
            
        
        
            
            var tile_layer_b2761496c65d46bf86a90b028be4d5f1 = L.tileLayer(
                'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
                {
                    maxZoom: 18,
                    minZoom: 1,
                    attribution: 'Data by <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>, under <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">ODbL</a>.',
                    detectRetina: false
                    }
                ).addTo(map_b2063da716d14361b72b0f9a50315884);

        
        
            

            var circle_marker_16be3d0af1084adbbb743bb146162d55 = L.circle(
                [37.38376,-5.9914],
                20,
                {
                    color: '#3186cc',
                    fillColor: '#3186cc',
                    fillOpacity: 0.6
                    }
                )
                .addTo(map_b2063da716d14361b72b0f9a50315884);
            
        
            
            var popup_0146596d5713425b90dd89b1beb77099 = L.popup({maxWidth: '800'});

            
                var i_frame_8bf40a55fcf94c2aae94317c7c942f95 = $('<iframe src="data:text/html;base64,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" width="800" height="500"></iframe>')[0];
                popup_0146596d5713425b90dd89b1beb77099.setContent(i_frame_8bf40a55fcf94c2aae94317c7c942f95);
            

            circle_marker_16be3d0af1084adbbb743bb146162d55.bindPopup(popup_0146596d5713425b90dd89b1beb77099);

            
        
        
            

            var circle_marker_0211ff4767b34184ad4c663e0b1d729c = L.circle(
                [37.383889,-5.991389],
                20,
                {
                    color: '#3186cc',
                    fillColor: '#3186cc',
                    fillOpacity: 0.6
                    }
                )
                .addTo(map_b2063da716d14361b72b0f9a50315884);
            
        
            
            var popup_b92b5fd312c94c00984279d5b1b86f69 = L.popup({maxWidth: '800'});

            
                var i_frame_2d42c75caa4245a59d6f07b1c9212cc8 = $('<iframe src="data:text/html;base64,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" width="800" height="500"></iframe>')[0];
                popup_b92b5fd312c94c00984279d5b1b86f69.setContent(i_frame_2d42c75caa4245a59d6f07b1c9212cc8);
            

            circle_marker_0211ff4767b34184ad4c663e0b1d729c.bindPopup(popup_b92b5fd312c94c00984279d5b1b86f69);

            
        
        
            

            var circle_marker_4cc91c97e25a4456b822e55f4ecb1549 = L.circle(
                [37.384,-5.992],
                20,
                {
                    color: '#3186cc',
                    fillColor: '#3186cc',
                    fillOpacity: 0.6
                    }
                )
                .addTo(map_b2063da716d14361b72b0f9a50315884);
            
        
            
            var popup_0b953df7a418459c8e72e0f5c1b0bb87 = L.popup({maxWidth: '800'});

            
                var i_frame_d059900a061a4549b59097ff5ee8b4d0 = $('<iframe src="data:text/html;base64,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" width="800" height="500"></iframe>')[0];
                popup_0b953df7a418459c8e72e0f5c1b0bb87.setContent(i_frame_d059900a061a4549b59097ff5ee8b4d0);
            

            circle_marker_4cc91c97e25a4456b822e55f4ecb1549.bindPopup(popup_0b953df7a418459c8e72e0f5c1b0bb87);

            
        
        
            

            var circle_marker_f36b000114d34c4480c0e3874b3a1aff = L.circle(
                [37.3925,-5.999722],
                20,
                {
                    color: '#3186cc',
                    fillColor: '#3186cc',
                    fillOpacity: 0.6
                    }
                )
                .addTo(map_b2063da716d14361b72b0f9a50315884);
            
        
            
            var popup_8b33998389c647748a4b7f558db9086f = L.popup({maxWidth: '800'});

            
                var i_frame_37f9728e7129448d8421dadcc3a5a7e7 = $('<iframe src="data:text/html;base64,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" width="800" height="500"></iframe>')[0];
                popup_8b33998389c647748a4b7f558db9086f.setContent(i_frame_37f9728e7129448d8421dadcc3a5a7e7);
            

            circle_marker_f36b000114d34c4480c0e3874b3a1aff.bindPopup(popup_8b33998389c647748a4b7f558db9086f);

            
        
        
            

            var circle_marker_c8f4a3824ab248d7b4516decbda1b587 = L.circle(
                [37.3899,-5.98711],
                20,
                {
                    color: '#3186cc',
                    fillColor: '#3186cc',
                    fillOpacity: 0.6
                    }
                )
                .addTo(map_b2063da716d14361b72b0f9a50315884);
            
        
            
            var popup_d59527a47f074edb946f6a17991ba6e3 = L.popup({maxWidth: '800'});

            
                var i_frame_c087ed2281544bcd954d25c51e54fcb3 = $('<iframe src="data:text/html;base64,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" width="800" height="500"></iframe>')[0];
                popup_d59527a47f074edb946f6a17991ba6e3.setContent(i_frame_c087ed2281544bcd954d25c51e54fcb3);
            

            circle_marker_c8f4a3824ab248d7b4516decbda1b587.bindPopup(popup_d59527a47f074edb946f6a17991ba6e3);

            
        
        
        
        </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to include html in popup="some text here", I have found that by default the folium module would escape all html syntax, so that it would display the actual syntax in the browser rather than processing it, so for example

```
'<' will becomes '&-l-t-;' without the dashes
```

I do not understand java whatsoever, so what I have done is: after the 'map.html' file is generated, I'd run another script to change the escape back into html syntax, this is dirty, the code is super bad, but its working for what I wanted to do.

```
def writeHTML(inputfile, outputfile):

    readfile_first = open(inputfile,'r')
    writefile_first = open(outputfile, 'w')

    for line in readfile_first:
        writefile_first.write(line.replace('&lt;','<'))

    readfile_first.close()
    writefile_first.close()

    readfile_second = open(outputfile, 'r')
    writefile_second = open(inputfile, 'w')

    for line in readfile_second:
        writefile_second.write(line.replace('&#34;','"'))

    readfile_second.close()
    writefile_second.close()

    readfile_third = open(inputfile, 'r')
    writefile_third = open(outputfile, 'w')

    for line in readfile_third:
        writefile_third.write(line.replace('&gt;','>'))

    readfile_third.close()
    writefile_third.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's possible with an iframe. I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pkeller3/95jfmwLa/1/) to test things out, but jsfiddle blocks my outgoing request for google.com and redirects back to jsfiddle login page. But it is a good proof of concept because it is loading an external page in the popup.

```
layer.bindPopup("<html><body><iframe src=&quot;http://www.google.com&quot;>
    <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p></iframe></body></html>");
```

I haven't tried it out but you could also try using jquery's load function.

Comment: Thanks @pk. It's a good start. I found the [reason](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8700636/2327328) why some pages can be embedded here and then found a [workaround](https://twitframe.com/) for twitter (my goal).

Comment: @philshem Can you post an example bindPopup call when you get it working? I'm curious to see how it works