# chrome extension-injected iframe is not working

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have js called iframeInjector

```js
var iFrame  = document.createElement ("iframe");
iFrame.src  = chrome.extension.getURL ("http://google.com");

document.body.insertBefore (iFrame, document.body.firstChild);
```

than I have this manifest:
{
    "manifest_version":         2,

```
"content_scripts":          [ {
    "js":       [ "iframeInjector.js" ],
    "matches":  [   "https://*/*","<all_urls>"
    ]
} ],
"description":              "Inject a google site",
"name":                     "Inject google",
"version":                  "1",
```

}
but when I open site iframe url is chrome-extension://dhnpacpfjbnmnbefjlfgemkphjilciak/http://google.com.
What Im doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`chrome.extension.getURL` is for local resouces only. You don't need to use it for HTTP links.

However, [Google expressly disallows embedding into iframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700636/how-to-show-google-com-in-an-iframe). It will detect running in a frame and will not work.

Comment: Yup that´s it.Ty for fast response.