# Github pages blocking direct links to Google?

Tags: html, github, github-pages

I forward my personal domain [http://xilagliu.org](http://xilagliu.org/)
to http://martinberger.github.io.  All links work fine, except for links to Google. See e.g. http://xilagliu.org/yyy.html

If I click on any of the google links, nothing happens, all other links work fine. 
I've tried this with various browswers on several machines. If I go to the original page http://martinberger.github.io/yyy.html all links work fine. If I open the google links in a new tab, that also works fine.

Does Github somehow block direct links to Google domains? What can I do to stop this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In http://martinberger.github.io/yyy.html, I don't see any target attached to the google links:

```
<a href="https://www.google.co.uk">Google.co.uk https</a>
```

Try adding a target attribute:

```
<a href="https://www.google.co.uk" target="_blank">Google.co.uk https</a>
```

Comment: That works, but why is is necessary only for the Google links. Indeed why is it necessary at all?

Comment: @MartinBerger I suspect because those links are, in your case, from within an iframe (see for instance: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8700754/6309)