# Why wont external sites embed?

Tags: embed, dokuwiki

I'm trying to embed the site mcmaster.com into a dokuwiki, and while a website like bbc.com loads just fine in an iframe, mcmaster and google.com do not load, they just display a blank screen. Is this because these sites allow not allowing embedding? Am I using the wrong syntax? I've also tried https.

```
{{url>http://www.google.com}}

<html>
<iframe width="1600" height="1200" src="http://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl"></iframe>
<iframe width="1024" height="768" src="http://www.bbc.com" style="-webkit-transform:scale(0.5);-moz-transform-scale(0.5);"></iframe>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Google is the problem. BBC should work.

"The reason for this is, that Google is sending an "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN" response header. This option prevents the browser from displaying iFrames that are not hosted on the same domain as the parent page."

Source: [How to show google.com in an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700636/how-to-show-google-com-in-an-iframe)

Your syntax is correct: https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:iframe
Make sure the plugin is installed correct.
Try with http://example.com/