# How do you use a URL javascript injection to create an iframe on any specified website?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, code-injection

I've looked for answers to this question, but the closest that I could find all had to do with using javascript to create an iframe on a user-owned page.  I specifically want to inject javascript into a website via the URL in order to add a frame to Google at the bottom of that website.  The syntax which I have been using is as follows:

```js
Javascript: var ifr=document.createElement('iframe');ifr.setAttribute("src","www.Google.com");ifr.width=100+'%';ifr.height=500+'px';document.body.appendChild(ifr); void(0);
```

Unfortunately, every time that I submit this, the iframe throws a 500 internal server error.  Can anybody lend advice as to why this may be happening?

Comment: You're missing the protocol.

Comment: Google does not like being put into frames also.

Comment: Related: [How to show google.com in an iframe?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8700636/464709)

Comment: Yoshi, could you please elaborate what you mean?

Comment: epascarello and Frédéric Hamidi, after further research into using Google specifically in iframes, I believe that that may be the issue here.  If somebody posts an answer with a bit more detail, I'll accept it.  Thanks.