# How to open window in frame

Tags: javascript, html

I learn JavaScript now, and encounter with next problem:
I have page with some frames, and I want to load some page into one of specified frames;
But code below does not do what I want.

Could you suggest please how could I load any url into specified frame?

```js
//"use strict";
function print(str) {
  document.write("<p><pre>" + str + "</pre></p>");
}

window.open("http://www.google.com", "topFrame");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Frameset Example</title>
</head>
<frameset rows="160,*">
  <frame name="topFrame">
    <frameset cols="50%,50%">
      <frame name="leftFrame">
        <frame name="rightFrame">
    </frameset>
</frameset>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5hnc2vzv/1/ something like this if you want to do it in javascript. But I see no reason not to do this in HTML directly

Comment: I just learn about window.open command and there is possibility to load url into frame but it does not work in my example

Comment: It will try top open a popup: http://jsfiddle.net/cmytz1bx/ If are on chrome like me you wil see a message in the upper right corner saying the popup is blocked

Comment: I have removed stars on window command - on my side it just open google.com in new window but not in topFrame

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-using-javascript

Comment: I do not want to open google.com in new tab. I want to open it in one of 3 frames which are present in current page

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_frame.asp not supported in HTML5

Answer (score 1):

In order to open a page within a frame, set the src attribute of the frame to the desired url.

```
<frame src="whateversite.html">
```

Note that frames are obsolete in HTML5.  Consider using an iframe to accomplish the same task, or jquery's load function
iframe: https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/iframe
jquery load: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: That is good, but how could I dynamically load google.com in some frame specified by name?

Comment: not supported frames is not the case because we could switch to html 4 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN” “http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">  and result the same

Comment: document.getElementById('myframe').src="www.mywebsite.html"  I only mentioned that they are obsolete so you can consider alternate options moving to future proof your page.  Also I believe google prevents you from loading their page into a frame,   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700636/how-to-show-google-com-in-an-iframe  If google was only for the sake of example you should be fine with your real site.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that I found why url does not loaded into frame
1) script is loaded before frames and it does not know about topFrame
2) I could do this loading from child frames for example like this

MainWindow.html:

```
<!--<!DOCTYPE html>-->  
<html lang=" EN" XMLNS="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Frameset Example</title>
</head>
<frameset rows="160,*">
    <frame src="frame.html" name="topFrame"/>
    <frameset cols="50%,50%">
        <frame src="frame.html" name="leftFrame"/>
        <frame src="frame.html" name="rightFrame"/>
    </frameset>
</frameset>
<body>
</body>
```

frame.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Frameset Example</title>
    <script>   
        window.open("http://korrespondent.net", "leftFrame");
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

But I still have question: how to run the script from MainWindow.html?
I want put next script into somewhere in MainWindow.html:

```
<script>   
    window.open("http://korrespondent.net", "leftFrame");
</script>
```

But it does not work

Answer (score 0):

I did additional research and here is correct answer:

MainWindow.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=" EN" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Frameset Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" defer src="LoadFrame.js"></script>
</head>
<frameset rows="160,*">
    <frame src="frame.html" name="topFrame" />
    <frameset cols="50%,50%">
        <frame src="frame.html" name="leftFrame" />
        <frame src="frame.html" name="rightFrame" />
    </frameset>
</frameset>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

frame.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Frameset Example</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

LoadFrame.js:

```
window.open("http://www.korrespondent.net", "leftFrame");
```

So to have possibility access to some inner frame we should use deferred loading of JavaScript