# why this script won't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Well what I need is a script what works as follow,

Each new time the page opens, the `iframe` has to pick 1 of the 50 link to show randomly as possible.
Now I did some research and I make the following script.
It works on JS(dot)DO but it won't work on jsbin and when I try Chrome it wont work. So i need a little help with it, I hope someone can help me with it!

```
<iframe id="frame"></iframe>
        <script>
            (function() {
                var e = document.getElementById('frame'),
                    f = function( el, url ) {
                        el.src = url;
                    },
                    urls = [           
                    'link1',
                      // all links 1/50
                    'link50'],
                    i = 0,
                    l = urls.length;
             f( e, urls[Math.round(Math.random()*50)] );
             })();


        </script>
```

(sorry for the bad English, It's not my main language

Comment: check the console for errors

Comment: I would have suggested to use the variable `l` and replace `Math.round` by `Math.floor`: `f(e, urls[Math.floor(Math.random() * l)]);`.

Comment: @Xufox `urls[Math.floor(Math.random()*(l-1))]` is more correct because the index 50 doesn't exist

Comment: @R3tep No. `Math.random()` can’t ever reach `1`, but will always be below it. When you multiply it by `l`, the number will always be less than `l` and if you then floor it, it will still be less than `l`.

Comment: I tryed the change but still the same result. I doensn't understand why one of the online script editor run it right and the other wont work right,

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all you can't simply open any link in `<iframe>` due to browser security restrictions. You can read more at [How to show google.com in an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700636/how-to-show-google-com-in-an-iframe).

Now let's talk about the code itself.

```
<iframe id="frame"></iframe>
    <script>
        (function() {
            var e = document.getElementById('frame'),
                f = function( el, url ) {
                    el.src = url;
                },
                urls = [           
                'link1',
                  // all links 1/50
                'link50'],
                i = 0,
                l = urls.length;
         f( e, urls[Math.round(Math.random()*50)] );
         })();


    </script>
```

Why do you set the `i` variable? You do not use it in your code, and can delete it. Why do you multiple `Math.random()` by `50` if you have `l`. Multiply it by `l` it's more convenient. Consider this example:

```
<div id="divID"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var e = document.getElementById('divID'),
  f = function( el, url ) {
      el.innerHTML = url;
  },
  urls = ['https://www.google.ru/', 'https://www.yandex.com/', 'http://www.bing.com/', 'https://www.yahoo.com/', 'https://duckduckgo.com/'],
  urlsLength = urls.length;
  f( e, urls[Math.floor( Math.random() * urlsLength )] );
</script>
```

You can check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/tfno031a/ (Just press the Run button in the upper left corner). You have to slightly modify it to load content into `<iframe>` (if you do have local urls). I hope this will help you. Good luck!

**EDIT**

Working example. I have a `1.html` file in the same directory with the main file. Also pay attention to `Math.floor()`, I was careless in the beginning.

```
<iframe id='iframeID'></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var e = document.getElementById('iframeID'),
  f = function( el, url ) {
    el.src = url;
  },
  urls = ['1.html'],
  urlsLength = urls.length;
  window.onload = f( e, urls[Math.floor( Math.random() * urlsLength )] );
</script>
```

Comment: i see now, thats much better but still i don't understand when i put a link in a iframe it works and when i add a link with the script it won't work, thats the last thing i need. with the div it works fine but only the iframe wont work for now

Comment: @nederlandb0y Several things I think might be wrong:
1. You didn't change innerHTML to src.
2. There is a wrong id.
3. Your DOM loads after the javascript. Set "on document ready" trigger to test it.
4. You use wrong path to the html file.

Comment: I still not understand i try but

<iframe id="frame"  </iframe>
<script>
$('document').ready(function(){});
var e = document.getElementById('frame')
      f = function( el, url ) {
          el.scr = url;
      },
      urls = ['http://test.com','http://test.com', 'http://test.com', 'http://test.com', 'http://test.com', 'http://test.com',],
      urlsLength = urls.length;
f( e, urls[Math.round( Math.random() * urlsLength )] );
</script>

Comment: @nederlandb0y would you please take a look at the edit section? Works for me.