# <HTML> iframe tag with hyperlink

Tags: html, iframe, hyperlink, href, target

I don't know why this code is not executed. 
I want to link the sites in an iframe

However, Daum and apple are executed, but other two sites, that is, naver and google are not executed. 
If I click that link (naver and google), no changes appear. What is the problem?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] and take the [tour] to see how to ask questions. HINT: Post the code instead of a picture of the code.
The reason that Google is not working in your iFrame is because they do not allow it. Press F12 to see the error message

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show google.com in an iframe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700636/how-to-show-google-com-in-an-iframe)