# Iframe chrome extension slow to load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, plugins

I've looked at a few questions and it seems this is a common problem for extensions that open pages with iframes. A solution i've seen is to add a  spinner gif and have it hide automatically after a few seconds using a for loop. I tried to do that and i couldnt get it to work. The gif only appears when the iframe has loaded (4+ seconds after i clicked the extension icon)

HTML:

```
<!--
<!doctype html>
 This page is shown when the extension button is clicked, because the
 "browser_action" field in manifest.json contains the "default_popup" key with
 value "popup.html".
 -->
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Google</title>
    <style>
html, body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
      body {
        font-family: "Segoe UI", "Lucida Grande", Tahoma, sans-serif;
        font-size: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    overflow-y:hidden;
      }
      #status {
        /* avoid an excessively wide status text */
        white-space: pre;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        overflow: hidden;
        max-width: 400px;
      }
    p{
            visibility:visible;
    }


    </style>

    <!--
      - JavaScript and HTML must be in separate files: see our Content Security
      - Policy documentation[1] for details and explanation.
      -
      - [1]: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy
     -->
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="status">
<img src="spinner.gif"/>
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/" width="398" height="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe> 

</body>
</html>
```

js:

```
for (var i = 1; i == 10; i++) {
document.getElementById(img).style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

Manifest file:

```
  {
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Open google",
"version": "1",
    "browser_action": {

      "default_icon": { 
        "19": "icon.png",
        "38": "icon.png"
      },
      "default_title": "Webpage opener",
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
  }
```

If i've broken any rules by asking this question, please comment below and i'll correct my question.

Answer (score 1):

First, I don't know since when, but we cannot display Google.com in an iframe.
([How to show google.com in an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700636/how-to-show-google-com-in-an-iframe))

Say you want to open Bing instead.

**As a rational thinking, the answer is like this.**

You might have the popup.html as follow:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Google</title>
</head>
<body>
  <img style="display: block" src="spinner.gif" />
  <iframe style="display: none" src="http://www.bing.com/" width="" height="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

It is simple. First, we show the spinner, and hide the iframe.
Then to achieve what you expected, the script might look like

```
$('iframe').load(function () {
    $('iframe').css('display', 'block');
    $('img').css('display', 'none');
});
```

For some lightning-speed pages like Google.com or Bing.com, you probably don't see the spinner.

**But in fact**

Google Chrome is so smart that is will wait until the iframe (or all the iframes) is loaded, then it show the popup.

So, a spinner is not needed.

Comment: I tried the what you sent me and the spinner never gets replaced by the iframe. It also takes a bit for the spinner to appear.

Comment: I plan on making this extension go to pages other than bing and google in the future so a spinner will be needed.

Comment: I am using Chrome 50 on Win10. What yours?

Comment: I am using chrome 50 on ubuntu 14.4

Comment: I can give you a screencast if you want to see what it looks like for me.

Comment: Yes please. Just get it on Youtube and give me the link.

Comment: The video is above