# How to add iframe element tag in dialog popup using html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I want to add an iframe inside a pop up dialog. How can I add it inside this dialog popup using JavaScript.

[Here is the dialog pop](https://jsfiddle.net/waqasadil/rwk1Ljcy/)  inside which I want to use an iframe.

Here is the Iframe tag that I want to show inside the popup. You can add any website in iframe. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
   <iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot display google.com inside an iFrame. Reason being that Google sends an "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN" response header. This option prevents the browser from displaying iFrames that are not hosted on the same domain as the parent page. This is a security feature to prevent click-jacking. Details at [How to show google.com in an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700636/how-to-show-google-com-in-an-iframe)

**EDIT after the 1st comment below:** 
I assume you want to load the iframe inside the dialog when "New Dialog" button is clicked. Can you try doing this:

```
last=$(<div/>").dialog(dialogOptions).dialogExtend(dialogExtendOptions).load("https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/");
```

Updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/rwk1Ljcy/1/

Comment: specifically adding google is not my main goal.I want to add just an iframe with any website link