# Azure Mobile Apps with Cordova Authentication

Tags: cordova, iframe, azure-mobile-services, content-security-policy

I've been following the [Microsoft guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-google-authentication) on how to use their Mobile App service to provide google login for a cordova app. I've set up the app service as described and registered my endpoint with the google+ API. I've set my content security policies to `unsafe-inline` where necessary in `index.html` (this is just for development), i.e.,

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data: gap: https://accounts.google.com https://something.azurewebsites.net; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

However, I'm currently getting the following error that's prevening the google login page from loading:

> Refused to display
>   'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=xxx..
>   in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

From reading this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41522652/refused-to-display-url-in-a-frame-because-it-set-x-frame-options-to-sameori) it would appear that it's not possible to show the google login in an iframe. How then am I suppose to provide google authentication for a cordova app that uses Azure's Mobile App service?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use [Cordova client plugin for Azure Mobile Apps](https://github.com/azure/azure-mobile-apps-cordova-client). With this plugin, you can call the platform to launch the login window instead of an iframe.

For more information, please refer to [Add authentication to your Apache Cordova app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-cordova-get-started-users).

Comment: I am using that plugin, but also had cordova-plugin-inappbrowser plugin installed that doesn't play nice with google's identity provider (doesn't like sameorigin on the iframe). I uninstalled that plugin, and appeared to get a little further, i.e., a new web window is opened. However, I now get this error `Not allowed to navigate top frame to data URL:`