# Open external website inside ion-content and cross communication using iFrame in ionic 3

Tags: cordova, iframe, ionic-framework

I am working on an ionic framework based mobile application. My project is a side menu based application. On clicking the item in the side menu, I need to load an external website inside ion-content and hide side menu of the loaded website but I can't figure it out how to do it.

I tried ngCordova InAppBrowser, but it loads website in a separate full screen.

I also tried iFrame, but I couldn't load the website inside ion-content. 
Getting following msg "refused to display url in a frame because it set 'x-frame-options' to 'sameorigin'". To avoid clickjacking, the x-frame-options in website is set to sameorigin.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site is not a code-writing service and is not meant for delivering complete solutions. Users are expected to show some effort and code whilst SO is here to help you solve specific programming problems along the way. Please show your code. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Refused to display 'url' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41522652/refused-to-display-url-in-a-frame-because-it-set-x-frame-options-to-sameori)

Comment: @e666 Is there any technique other than iFrame to load a website inside ion-content and cross communication in ionic 3? Note: The website which I'm trying to load has been developed by one of my team mate.

Comment: @DominicFrancis Did you get any solution yet? I am searching for a same solution.