# Google street view is not showing on a website

Tags: google-maps, google-street-view

I am trying to embed a Google Map and street view on a website. The postcode, latitude and longtitude are stored in databases which are OK and my code is:

```
<iframe width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"
                src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q={{ $code[0] }}%20{{$code[1]}}&key=MYKEY" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                <hr />
                  <iframe src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400x400&location={{ $pc[0]['latitude'] }},{{ $pc[0]['longtitude'] }}&fov=80&heading=70&pitch=0&key=MYKEY&signature=MYSIGNATURE" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

PHP is returning this OK as

```
 <iframe width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"
                src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=BA1%204HX&key=MYKEY" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                <hr />
                  <iframe src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400x400&location=51.398734,-2.3936212&fov=80&heading=70&pitch=0&key=AMYKEY&signature=MYSIGNATURE" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

The problem is that the map is fine and correct but the street view is a blank.

I have looked on Frefox tools for rejection or anything by Google but there is nothing.

Comment: Do you get this error in the console: `Refused to display 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400x400&location=51.398734,-2.3936212&fov=80&heading=70&pitch=0&key=MYKEY' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Refused to display 'url' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41522652/refused-to-display-url-in-a-frame-because-it-set-x-frame-options-to-sameori)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set 'X-Frame-Options' on iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27358966/how-to-set-x-frame-options-on-iframe)

Comment: There is nothing in the response header - it is blanl

Comment: The request is not being refused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon trying your sample code, I was getting the `Refused to display .... in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'` error : [image: error]

Please note that Street View Static API is meant to be embedded within an `<img>` tag's src attribute like this:

```
<img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400x400&location=51.398734,-2.3936212&fov=80&heading=70&pitch=0&key=YOUR_API_KEY&signature=SIGNATURE"/>
```

To resolve this, you can either load the Street View Static image in an `<img>` tag as above, or use Street View Mode for [Maps Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide#street_view_mode) which would look something like this:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/streetview?location=51.398734,-2.3936212&fov=80&heading=70&pitch=0&key=YOUR_API_KEY" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```