# onmouseover function unresponsive to certain <img> tags?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, onmouseover

HTML code:

```
<body>
1 <img src="https://n.sinaimg.cn/sinacn10104/334/w1319h2215/20190107/c4a8-hrfcctn3630013.jpg" alt="guy" width="220" height="300"
2   style="float:left; padding:20px">
3    <img src="https://n.sinaimg.cn/sinacn10104/334/w1319h2215/20190107/c4a8-hrfcctn3630013.jpg" alt="guy" width="220" height="300"
4    style="float:left; padding:20px">
5    <img src="https://stat.dokusho-ojikan.jp/dab52813-fbde-4b44-bbb2-6eea12b5bb35.jpg" alt="guy" width="300" height="423"
6    style="float:left">
   
   

  
7   <p><div class="rap"></div></p>
 
8   <p><div class="rap" id="n" style="float:left; position: absolute; left:1800px; top:16px"></div></p>
 
9  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/YjG8SgN/SG8ZEag.png" alt="guy" id="ki" width="367" height="644" 
10  style="float:left; position: absolute; left:930px; top:431px">
11  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/8f/a7/b9/8fa7b999f20538fe753013f69a8f441c.jpg" width="433" height="580" 
12    style="float:left; position: absolute; left:1300px; top:431px">
13    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/82/59/86/82598611fcf7003ca9cbd146085c3c1e.jpg" width="362" height="453" 
14    style="float:left; position: absolute; left:560px; top:431px">
15    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/AcodYxf.jpeg" width="183" height="229" 
16    style="float:left; position: absolute; left:300px">

     <div class="os"></div>
  
   
  
       

<p><div class="ra"></div>
   <p><div class="ra" style="float:left; position: absolute; left:1900px; top:4798px"></div></p>
   <img src="https://i.imgur.com/AcodYxf.jpeg" alt="guy" width="285" height="160"
   style="float:left; position: absolute; left: 1700px; top:16px">
   <img src="https://i.imgur.com/AcodYxf.jpeg" alt="guy" width="285" height="160"
   style="float:left; position: absolute; left: 1700px; top:350px">
   
   
   https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp

</body>
```

CSS code:

```
#n{
background-position: 40% 45%; 
}

.rap{
    background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/rDDRGYE.jpg");
    background-attachment: sticky;
    background-position: 77% 45%;
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 40%;  
    color: lightcyan;
    background-color: slategrey;
}

.ra{
    background-image: url("https://cdn.boldmethod.com/images/blog/lists/2016/03/11-facts-about-the-harrier-jump-jet/4.jpg");
    background-attachment: sticky;
    background-position: 71% 90%;
    height: 630px;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: slategrey;
}

.os{
    height: 4350px;
    width:  100%;
    opacity: 0;
    background-color: slategrey; 
}

body {
 
  background-image: url("https://files.yande.re/image/43e9ae14c74ba30fe78e66e30caea227/yande.re%20403366%20business_suit%20kono_subarashii_sekai_ni_shukufuku_wo%21%20megumin%20mishima_kurone%20raratina_dustiness_ford%20witch.jpg");
  width: 2820 px;
  height: 2050 px;
  background-position-y: 80%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: azure;
}
```

Javascript code:

```
 let links = document.querySelectorAll("[src], [href]");
links.forEach(link => {
  link.addEventListener("mouseover", e => {
    const href = e.target.href;
    const src = e.target.src;
      if (src) location.assign(src);
   
  });
});
```

I aim to trigger onmouseover function for all images here.

So far this mouseover function() works nicely on the  tags generally. However, from HTML code  lines 9 - 16, the mouseover function does not seem to work immediately on those images.

If I'm lucky, they take a long time to trigger, or that I have to onmouseover the top of those images. Yet mostly the onmouseover will not activate for images within HTML lines 9 - 16. What is disabling the onmouseover for those images?

Thanks for helpful answers.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Also, please don't use irrelevant tags - or is this problem in any way related to CSS?

Comment: Minimum examples always get more attention.

Comment: Can you clarify what the (otherwise) empty div with class os is doing immediately after some of the images. It has opacity 0. It is preventing the mouseovers from being seen by the images (which are underneath it). There is quite a confused static versus absolute positioned elements in this code.

Comment: @Nico Haase funny thing is that, when I move HTML lines 9-16 under another div tag, `<p><div class="ra" style="float:left; position: absolute; left:1900px; top:4798px"></div></p>`, the onmouseover function actually triggers. 

I just want to know why html lines 9-16 currently isn't hoverable.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Such JS code could simply be debugged using your browser's built-in developer tools

Comment: @AHaworth regarding <div> .os{}, I merely wanted some empty transparent space to put my <img> tags. 

"It is preventing the mouseovers from being seen by the images (which are underneath it). "

While this is plausable, I only wanted to test if the mouseover could detect any getAttributeAll(), namely src in this case, no matter the type of html page.

Comment: @NicoHaase, as mentioned earlier, I moved HTML lines 9-16 under <div> with class="ra".

Where I'm stuck was, placing HTML lines 9-16 under <div> class="rap", line 8. Yet later on, I had no issue with onmouseover function(), after placing HTML lines 9-16 under <div class="ra">.

Funnily enough the mouseover seemed to work properly. 

Also, I'll try using my browser's built in developer tools, as you suggested.

Comment: @AHaworth funny thing is that <div class="rap"> HTML line 7 does not seem to prevent mouseover from seeing the images before it, like how <div class="os"> behind line 16 does to the images before it. 


Does opacity somehow prevent mouseover from detecting those pics?

Comment: An element which overlays other elements will see the hover (opacity doesn't get rid of the element).

Comment: @AHaworth  edit: regarding  class os, I did remove background-color from it and now mouseover works perfectly now. 

That said, I thought that onmouseover - and by extension other functions such as QuerySelectorAll() or getElementsByTagName() can still detect tags or other such attributes, regardless of css attributs like opacity. I thought css is for human vision, whose actual presence is still readable by the browser and IDE itself..

Comment: If you've got one element on top of another which has any sort of background color it will detect a hover. Not the same as querying by selector which is looking at the structure of the DOM.

Comment: @AHaworth I'll take into consideration what you just said, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the images that aren't working are either:

1. Ones that you've loaded in with CSS (and therefore don't have href or src HTML attributes for JS to look for), or
2. They are images that are covered by the large CSS-loaded divs rendered on top of them so they aren't hoverable.

I would recommend just including your images as HTML <img> tags and giving them a src attribute so your JS function can look for them. However, keep in mind the more conventional way of looking for this in JS this would be to assign it a specific class and query for the class instead of the src property.

```html
<!-- Try making these img tags with src properties instead of loading them through CSS -->
<div><img class="rap" src="https://i.imgur.com/rDDRGYE.jpg"></img></div>
```

Try the HTML solution above instead of loading them through CSS like you originally had below.

```css
.rap {
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/rDDRGYE.jpg");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I do know some images were CSS loaded. I plan to develop a onmouseover function() capable of accessing such css loaded images at a later date.

Comment: Oh great! It looked like the elements that were CSS loaded were growing too large and overlapping the others, making some of them unclickable.
Or was I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: yes, the css loaded was growing too large, and overlapped the others causing them to be unclickable.

Comment: If it's not too much to ask, would you mind accepting it as an answer? I'd like to be able to finally upvote answers I find useful on the site, lol. Thanks!

Comment: done. I accepted your answer by ticking next to your comment.

Answer (score 1):

The image url you are passing is having issue while loading onmouseover at line : location.assign(src);.

Refused to display 'https://imgur.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.
[image]

As you cannot change X-Frame-Options, try to load with different url in image src or refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41522652/refused-to-display-url-in-a-frame-because-it-set-x-frame-options-to-sameori).

Comment: Funny thing is when i place HTML lines 9-16 under the `<div class="os"></div>`, the onmouseover function works nicely for them.