# social media url,s not loading from the html iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

i am trying to open a facebook and twitter url in an iframe but its not loading even though its loading the other url,s like in the code w3school is able to load.

```
facebook
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/" height="900"></iframe>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4" ng-controller=twitter-controller>
twitter 
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com" height="900"></iframe>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4" ng-controller="instagram-controller">
instagram   
<iframe src="http://www.twitter.com" height="900"></iframe>
```

Comment: This is no valid code! There is a closing div without an opening one

Comment: Some website won't load in iframes, they prevent that using [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options)

Comment: @SankarRaj then what will be the other ways to achive the same just for the information i am using angularjs as javascript

Comment: @irfanshafi I'm saying you can't do this. https://jsfiddle.net/s0ej1gLy/ see the console in the fiddle for more info...

Comment: @SankarRaj i mean to ask that there is no other alternative way to achieve this ??

Comment: @irfanshafi Simply, no alternatives. for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700636/how-to-show-google-com-in-an-iframe. one thing you can do is http://stackoverflow.com/a/8701003/2131576