# Iframe doesnt show any thing for major sites

Tags: html, security, iframe

I'm trying find out constraint with `Iframe` usages.

Below lines worked fine and I can see content in Iframe:

```
<iframe src="https://www.w3schools.com/" height="500" width="500"></iframe>

<iframe src="https://www.w3.org/" height="500" width="500"></iframe>
```

But these lines doesn't work:

```
<iframe src="https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/" height="500" width="500"></iframe>

<iframe src="https://www.google.com/" height="500" width="500"></iframe>
```

How to determine which websites can be supported in a `iframe` and which were not? Is there a way to find that out without displaying it in `iframe`? I want to display a message when user types a `URL` to inform him that `web site is not supported in iframe`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show google.com in an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700636/how-to-show-google-com-in-an-iframe)

Comment: My question is slightly different. I'm trying to find out a way so that I can find out if it would be possible to show a particular site at my page or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many websites send an "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN" response header which prevents you from displaying them in an iframe. This option prevents the browser from displaying iframes that are not hosted on the same domain as the parent page. This is a security feature to prevent click-jacking. [see more](https://barney.0x539.se/X-Frame-Options/)

After doing my own test, I'm assuming you were testing within w3school's tryit.asp editor, which is why w3schools worked but the others didn't.

Also, w3.org doesn't send "x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN" which is why it works from other domains.

Here's an image showing the error which prevents the iframe from showing
[image: here's an image showing the error which prevents the iframe from showing]

Comment: yes, I was using w3school's tryit. But it worked even for https://www.w3.org/ and https://therunningbug.com/ from the same tryit page.

Comment: edited my answer, w3.org doesn't send a sameorigin header, and I'm guessing therunningbug.com doesn't either.

Comment: Is there a way to find which site has set `X-Frame-Options` to `sameorigin`?

Comment: if the site isn't showing then you can inspect element and check errors for something like the picture in my answer.