# I want to use embedded Browser inside of my WebPage in React

Tags: reactjs, embedded-browser

so I have a task to make a Browser embedded into my web Page.
I have a React project (I do NOT have a React-native project)

I tried this one: [react-embedded-browser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-embedded-browser)

but it seems that's deprecated (the last update was 3 years ago) and any other I find is for react-Native that I do not need. I need embedded browser only in React.

I need something like this:
[image]

**Is there any React Embedded-Browser Solutions?**

Comment: Do you only need to do a web search? are you wanting to fully embed a browser?

Comment: I want to fully embed a browser.

Comment: I don't know of any react specific solutions, you can create an iframe based browser however with Google you will need to fiddle with your proxy to change your url to match Googles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my comments here is some more information on alternative options:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-fetch

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/tutorial/creatingcse

[How to show google.com in an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700636/how-to-show-google-com-in-an-iframe/8700754)