# Loading IFrame with external URL in Ext.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iframe, ext.net

I create a `Window` in my Ext.NET desktop. My Window definition is:

```
var window = new Window
{
   ID = "MyID",
   Title = "Window Title", 
   MinWidth = 600,
   MinHeight = 400,
   CloseAction = CloseAction.Destroy,
   Loader = new ComponentLoader
   {
       Url = "http://www.google.com",
       Mode = LoadMode.Frame,
       LoadMask = { ShowMask = true }
   }
};
```

and this is added to a new `DesktopModule`. The code for this is:

```
public static DesktopModule Create(MyModel model)
{
    var module = DesktopModuleHelper.CreateModule(new ModuleProperties
    {
        Id = "MyId",
        Index = 6,
        Model = model,
        Cls = "x-app-myapp"
    });

    window.IconCls = "x-app-sm x-app-myapp";
    module.Window.Add(window);

    return module;
}
```

and then I use this to make the module visible:

```
@(x.Desktop().Modules(
    Create(MyModel.Create(), "http://www.google.com")))
```

The issue I'm having is that then I click on the shortcut for this module, it shows a gray box with the text "www.google.com refused to connect.". I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I think it has something to do with how I'm declaring `Loader` but I'm not sure which values are incorrect.

Comment: Did you try different Url for your iFrame? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700636/how-to-show-google-com-in-an-iframe

Comment: @Peska Thanks! Trying `https://www.pizzahut.com/` fixed my issue

Comment: @Peska Add that as an answer and I'll accept it