# How to set other site on canvas in html 5?

Tags: javascript, html, web, html5-canvas

i want open google.com in my website like browser , i can set website on canvas ?
or have any way to solve ?

```
<img id="scream" src="https://www.google.com/" alt="The Scream" width="220" height="277">
```

Comment: This would usually be done with an iframe, not a canvas. However, Google will not allow it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700636/how-to-show-google-com-in-an-iframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **iframe** tag, like this:

```html
<iframe style="width: 100%; height: 300px; overflow: hidden" src="https://www.google.com/webhp?igu=1"></iframe>
```

Comment: Have you actually tried this? I guarantee you it will not work with `https://www.google.com`.

Comment: You are right!! This example dosen't work with google website. Here is the reason: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700636/how-to-show-google-com-in-an-iframe

Comment: try this not work , i mean not open website only write www.google.com refused to connect.

Comment: You can change for this URL: https://www.google.com/webhp?igu=1. I tested it! Its Works!

Comment: not work, ifram use only youtube ,  try
<iframe width="420" height="345" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY">
</iframe>

Comment: Its works! You need put a complete URL with **HTTP://** like this:  "http://youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY"

Comment: thanks work now for google but i google.com for example used, i want set  'https://www.oanda.com/currency/converter/ 'in my website why not work for this website ?

Comment: When you use this link the error message returned is: **'https://www.oanda.com/lang/pt/' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'**

Its means that the server allow iframe loading only from a page hosted on the same domain. You can´t use this site in your iframe, outside from server (.oanda.com)