# How can I fix the display problem on my iframe

Tags: iframe

I tried creating an iframe code for the below Google URL

https://www.google.com/travel/hotels/Nigeria?g2lb=4207875%2C4208993%2C4223281%2C4237923%2C4240602%2C4241911%2C4242898%2C4243602%2C4247457%2C4244078%2C4246257&hl=en&gl=ng&un=1&q=nigeria%20hotels&rp=OAJAAEgC&ictx=1&ved=2ahUKEwi4z4iWt5XhAhVbSxUIHXwJAewQvDF6BAgMEDI&hrf=CgUImHUQACIDTkdOKhYKBwjjDxAEGAwSBwjjDxAEGA0YASgAsAEAmgEJEgdOaWdlcmlhogETCggvbS8wNWNndhIHTmlnZXJpYZIBAiAB&tcfs=Ei0KCC9tLzA1Y2d2EgdOaWdlcmlhGhgKCjIwMTktMDQtMTISCjIwMTktMDQtMTNSAA

Here is the iframe code ,but ,it displays a blank page and I don't know how to fix it.
Please suggest a better way to do this ,I want the iframe to be on my site .Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's a similar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8700636/6517383)
And the accepted answer fits your question as well.

> The reason for this is, that Google is sending an "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN" response header. This option prevents the browser from displaying iFrames that are not hosted on the same domain as the parent page.

See: [Mozilla Developer Network - The X-Frame-Options response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header)

Comment: Thanks for your reply ,I will read the thread and find out if there is a way to do it .