# Open webpage in the middle frame, using bootstrap vertical tabs template

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, frame

I have downloaded a bootstrap template with vertical tabs and what appears to be a main frame.

[screenshot of current web page view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ok2a.png)

I want to be able to click on '**Google**' (the link on the left) and for the google page to come up in the main frame, i.e where it currently says "This is where I want pages to show"

Currently, when I click 'Google', google is brought up in its own page, separately.

This is obviously the line that relates to what I want, and I have tried adding various html additions, but to no avail.

```
 <a href="https://www.google.com"  class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Google</a>
```

I get that I could include content within the page itself and link in various ways to that content (e.g using divs and containers) but I need it done this way, as all the links are going to be individual websites or pages and I need for them to be accessible inside this middle frame, in each case.

Could anyone suggest a solution and provide the code to add here please?

**My code (index page)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <title>Vertical</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="css/simple-sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

  <div class="d-flex" id="wrapper">

    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div class="bg-light border-right" id="sidebar-wrapper">
      <div class="sidebar-heading">Start Bootstrap </div>
      <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
        <a href="https://www.google.com"  class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Google</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Shortcuts</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Overview</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Events</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Profile</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Status</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div id="page-content-wrapper">

      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light border-bottom">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="menu-toggle">Toggle Menu</button>

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>

      <div class="container-fluid">
        <h1 class="mt-4">This is where I want pages to show</h1>
        <p>e,g, when I click Google on the left, I'd like the page (or site) to show in the frame, and will appear non-collapsed on larger screens. When toggled using the button below, the menu will change.</p>
        <p>Make sure to keep all page content within the <code>#page-content-wrapper</code>. The top navbar is optional, and just for demonstration. Just create an element with the <code>#menu-toggle</code> ID which will toggle the menu when clicked.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->

  </div>
  <!-- /#wrapper -->

  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
  <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Menu Toggle Script -->
  <script>
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>



  [1]: https://i.st
```

ack.imgur.com/JvcRb.png

Answer (score 0):

Well, in order to see a website inside a website you need to use the [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) element.
But Google (as other sites) forbid that [option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700636/how-to-show-google-com-in-an-iframe)