# Not able to show iframe in html

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add an **iframe** but getting an error. Here is my Code:

```
  <html>
    <head>
        <title>Adding Iframe</title>
    </head> 
    <body>
        <iframe src="https://www.google.com/" height="300px" width="100%" name="iframe_a" id="if1">
        </iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Codepen: 
https://codepen.io/multanisadik/pen/xxKmVeB

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I think the reason is the `cross-origin`.

Comment: @Jin Can you please tell me how can solve this problem?

Comment: I think it is impossible if the sites(eg google.com) set `X-Frame-Option` to **SAMEORIGIN**.

Comment: This is also important. thanks for helping me out...

Answer (score 2):

You can't show google in an iframe. Most of the well-known site block these features.

The reason for this, they sent a response header called **X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN**. This option prevents the browser from displaying iframe.

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing anything wrong actually.
Try with https://Wikipedia.com instead and it will work the reason it is not working for you is as the comment states and a more elaborate answer can be here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8700754/6445892

TLDR: google won’t allow you, try with another site and it will work ;)

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I have tried https://codepen.io/ instead of https://www.google.com/ and it's working. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

The iframe tag isn't enabled for every website, some websites don not permit that kind of access. Google is one of them.