# How to fix "Blocked a frame with origin "https://example.org" from accessing a cross-origin frame."

Tags: iframe, google-chrome-extension, x-frame-options

For my personal use, I'm trying to show https://maps.google.com inside an iframe. Note: I am **NOT** looking to use Google's Embed API.

Here's what I've done:

- use a Chrome Extension to remove the following request headers: `X-Frame-Options`, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`
- add instead these headers: `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *`, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`, `Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors *;`
- the above is done on ALL request headers on ALL urls (`browser.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener` in my extension), it's super permissive, but for now I'm just trying to make it work.

Now I'm trying to do `<iframe src=" https://maps.google.com" />`.

It works half-way:

- I see Google Maps showing on my iframe
- But there's a permanent "Loading..." text on the bottom, and I cannot click on markers or search stuff (see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9iDG.jpg)).
- I get the following error in the console:

```
Blocked autofocusing on a form control in a cross-origin subframe.
maps:13 Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.google.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
    at Object._.Hr (https://www.google.com/maps/_/js/k=maps.m.en.dc5HEiFGHqQ.O/m=sc2,per,mo,lp,ti,ds,stx,bom,b/rt=j/d=1/rs=ACT90oFcxIV8Ad7kvBMCB_zNoSobKCZYEw:210:51)
    at /maps/_/js/k=maps.m.en.dc5HEiFGHqQ.O/m=vwr,vd,a,owc,ob,sp,en,smi,sc,vlg,log,smr,as,wrc/rt=j/d=1/ed=1/exm=sc2,per,mo,lp,ti,ds,stx,bom,b/rs=ACT90oFcxIV8Ad7kvBMCB_zNoSobKCZYEw:3599:3
    at /maps/_/js/k=maps.m.en.dc5HEiFGHqQ.O/m=vwr,vd,a,owc,ob,sp,en,smi,sc,vlg,log,smr,as,wrc/rt=j/d=1/ed=1/exm=sc2,per,mo,lp,ti,ds,stx,bom,b/rs=ACT90oFcxIV8Ad7kvBMCB_zNoSobKCZYEw:4990:3
    at NLa (https://www.google.com/maps/_/js/k=maps.m.en.dc5HEiFGHqQ.O/m=sc2,per,mo,lp,ti,ds,stx,bom,b/rt=j/d=1/rs=ACT90oFcxIV8Ad7kvBMCB_zNoSobKCZYEw:1677:132)
    at LLa.next (https://www.google.com/maps/_/js/k=maps.m.en.dc5HEiFGHqQ.O/m=sc2,per,mo,lp,ti,ds,stx,bom,b/rt=j/d=1/rs=ACT90oFcxIV8Ad7kvBMCB_zNoSobKCZYEw:1676:469)
    at IIa.f [as H] (https://www.google.com/maps/_/js/k=maps.m.en.dc5HEiFGHqQ.O/m=sc2,per,mo,lp,ti,ds,stx,bom,b/rt=j/d=1/rs=ACT90oFcxIV8Ad7kvBMCB_zNoSobKCZYEw:1561:184)
    at RIa (https://www.google.com/maps/_/js/k=maps.m.en.dc5HEiFGHqQ.O/m=sc2,per,mo,lp,ti,ds,stx,bom,b/rt=j/d=1/rs=ACT90oFcxIV8Ad7kvBMCB_zNoSobKCZYEw:1556:332)
    at eJa (https://www.google.com/maps/_/js/k=maps.m.en.dc5HEiFGHqQ.O/m=sc2,per,mo,lp,ti,ds,stx,bom,b/rt=j/d=1/rs=ACT90oFcxIV8Ad7kvBMCB_zNoSobKCZYEw:1565:43)
    at vA.Ma (https://www.google.com/maps/_/js/k=maps.m.en.dc5HEiFGHqQ.O/m=sc2,per,mo,lp,ti,ds,stx,bom,b/rt=j/d=1/rs=ACT90oFcxIV8Ad7kvBMCB_zNoSobKCZYEw:1564:405)
    at mb (https://www.google.com/maps/_/js/k=maps.m.en.dc5HEiFGHqQ.O/m=sc2,per,mo,lp,ti,ds,stx,bom,b/rt=j/d=1/rs=ACT90oFcxIV8Ad7kvBMCB_zNoSobKCZYEw:1563:293)
```

Any ideas on what I could try next to make this work? Or is it just plainly not possible?

Answer (score 3):

**Short Answer:** This can't be done.

**Long Answer:** [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) is decided at the server side. What this means is, the one opening the page doesn't decide if document can be opened in `iframe`, instead author of document decides it. In this case, its Google.

I tried achieving the same thing way back with Google search where you type a word in text box and hitting submit will pop an `iframe` with Google results. I did some research and learned it can't be done since Google doesn't allow different origins to display their pages.

That's why they have APIs.

More about this - [How to show google.com in an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8700636/)