# how to open a web browser in python paragraph in Jupiter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter

I am using Anaconda Jupyter notebook, in one of the paragraph i want to open a google search browser i dont want to open the google.com in a new tab.

With the below code i am able to open the google.com but it opens in new tab.

I need a function that will open a web browser in the output part where we get the results.

I tried the below code:

Code:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('https://www.google.com/', new=2)
```

please help, thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
%%html
<iframe src="https://playground.tensorflow.org" width="1200" height="1000"></iframe>
```

Or this:

```
from IPython.display import IFrame

url = 'https://playground.tensorflow.org'
IFrame(url, width=800, height=400)
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/ - could please try this link, its not working for me. getting this message - This content can’t be shown in a frame

Comment: See the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700636/how-to-show-google-com-in-an-iframe. Basically `google` does not permit cross-origin framing

Comment: You can try using `url = 'https://www.google.com?igu=1'`, works for me at least

Comment: yes this is working for me now. thank you for all the help.