# How can I open a https website inside HTML Iframe?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to open a https website from a html iframe but I am not able to do so. The code I am using is -`<iframe style="min-height:98vh" src="https://www.google.com" width="100%"></iframe>`

How can I do this?

Comment: You can't open google.com in an iframe period. It sets a header that tells the browser to disallow using in an iframe.

Comment: This is a security concern , to  quote the error. `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource `. It is highly recommended not try to access another domain from one's domain. It can end up in high vulnarebility

Comment: duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700636/how-to-show-google-com-in-an-iframe

This has already required answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open a site that is over 'https', you can use it like the code below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>HTML Iframes</h2>
<p>You can also use the CSS height and width properties to specify the size of the iframe:</p>

<iframe src="https://www.kuflink.com" style="height:250px;width:100%"></iframe>
<iframe src="https://www.flipkart.com" style="height:250px;width:100%"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Now if you can see the first site is loaded into an iFrame, even if it is with https but the second one gets a connection refused. even if you try [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/) in an iframe it will do the same. You can inspect your code and post the error that you are getting. This I think will be of X-frame options. You can read furthermore here for [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options)

Comment: You can also look for best practices. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/121800/https-iframe-embedded-in-http-page-pci-implications