# How to imbed google.com in website (flask)

Tags: python, html, flask

Is it possible to imbed google.com in a flask website?, i mean google.com as the **WHOLE** app if there is a way to do it please provide code and or "HTML" :)

my code host code:

```
from flask import Flask,render_template
import socket
import webbrowser

app = Flask('app')

@app.route('/')

def HTML():
    with open('HTML_CODE.TXT','r') as HTML:
        return(HTML.read())



hostname = socket.gethostname()
IP = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)



app.run(host=str(IP), port=8080)
```

Inside HTML.TXT:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 

<body style="background-color:LightGreen;">

<head>

    <title>GOOGLE_IMBED</title>
    
</head> 
  
<body> 
    <center> 
        <h1 style="color:Black;">GOOGLE_IMBED</h1> 
    </center> 
    <div> 
        <h1 style="color:Black;">Search:</h1>
        <input type="text" alt="Id:" align="right"> 
        
    </div> 
</body> 
  
</html>
```

Comment: You can't: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700636/how-to-show-google-com-in-an-iframe