# Can't open google drive folder in an iframe

Tags: html, iframe

I have access to a folder in google drive, I am logged in and I am trying to open the folder url in iframe.

I get this exception:
[image]

I understand the concept of same origin. Is there any way to bypass this or make it work?

Comment: you may not be able to do so , check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783095/how-can-i-bypass-the-x-frame-options-sameorigin-http-header

Comment: thanks @MrMisery seems like can't be done