# unable to load external website using iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

i am trying to load external website on my webpage using i frame but its giving following error on console.

here is my code

```
 <body>
  <iframe src="https://firebase.google.com/"> </iframe>
 </body>
```

error on console

```
Refused to display 'https://firebase.google.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
```

i try different solution but its not working .how to solve this problem?

Comment: It's [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3045101/2581562)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set 'X-Frame-Options' on iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27358966/how-to-set-x-frame-options-on-iframe)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error I think you need to change the 'X-Frame-Options' to allow the site to be loaded (if you have access to the server). Follow this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) to know how to do that.

However, if the domain that you are trying to access is setting the 'X-Frame-Options' to sameorigin then you can't display it in an iframe. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27358966/how-to-set-x-frame-options-on-iframe?rq=1) is similar to yours. Have a look at it.

Comment: I don't think OP will be able to adapt response headers sent by Google ;-)

Comment: Yeah @Ward, just did some more research. :)

Comment: is there any way solve  'X-Frame-Options' to sameorigin  on client side

Comment: Read about [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) here.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

The [`X-Frame-Options`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) header is meant precisely to prevent the page from being loaded in an iframe. e.g. to prevent [clickjacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking) attacks.