# Refused to display 'https://url.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'

Tags: javascript, php, iframe

I checked almost more then 100 answers about this question into Stackoverflow, but none of them resolved my problem. So i have a ready code about this problem, what is causing this.

```
<iframe src="{$ad_info.url}" id="pgl" class="surfer_frame" frameborder = "0"></iframe>
```

Can someone to give me some tip what to change here, so HTTPS sites to be shown into iframe. Thanks

Comment: The remote site won't allow you to show their site in a frame, because their web server has `X-Frame-Options` set to `sameorigin`. This is a security feature.

Comment: So i must contact server tech to help me about this? Right? Or i can do something.

Comment: Yeah, contact them. If they'll allow it, then they can add you to a whitelist.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How Can I Bypass the X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN HTTP Header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783095/how-can-i-bypass-the-x-frame-options-sameorigin-http-header)